# Solr-how do I get the final query after it has gone through all the analyzers

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I am a new solr user , 
just wanted to know how can I get the final value of q after it has gone through all the analyzers.
Ex original query q=ABC;"de

Analyzers = lowercase,Patternreplacefactory replacing semicons and other special characters

Output = abcde

Based on this abcde I am doing further processing in my code.
        @Override
        public void prepare(ResponseBuilder rb) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SolrQueryRequest req = rb.req;

```
    SolrParams params = req.getParams();
    String q = params.get("q");
```

This q value is ABC;"de 
how do a retrieve the output of the analyzers? or am I looking in the wrong method? I want to retrieve abcde

Answer (score 0):

you go to the [analysis](http://your.server:8983/solr/core0/admin/analysis.jsp?highlight=on) page and you can enter your query in Field Value (Query) side to see how it is analysed. Also add debugQuery=true to your request and study debug output

Comment: I got how to do that in the code . Thanks anyways :)  tokenStream = analyzer.reusableTokenStream(qf, new StringReader("your query"));